# Getting import could not be resolved Pylance error from one file in workspace but not the other

Tags: python

I have a few files in my workspace and in two of them I want to import the same two files from a folder. In my main file I do not get an error but in the other I do. I can't seem to understand why they would be different. And how to fix the issue?[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the main and other files?

Comment: @terrybozzio do you want the code or file locations? sorry not to sure what this problem entails